# No power in bedroom and bathroom

Tags: receptacle

I have no lights in my bathroom and have two receptacles and the light in my bedroom that don't work. I replaced the gfci in my bathroom and it works, i have reset it too. The light in my closet works. The other outlets in my bathroom work.

Comment: Do you know if all these lights and receptacles are on the same circuit?

Comment: Did it all work before you replaced the GFCI?

Comment: Did you wire the GFCI properly? Load vs line?

Comment: What is the age of your house?

Comment: Threephase, i do not know if they are, but how would I check to find out?  Harper, no they didn't, one day it all just stopped, gfci did keep tripping and wouldn't reset. Jeff, I think i did, i have a tester, the lights lit up with the reading that it was, i plugged a lamp into it and it worked, i hit the reset button and it worked.

Comment: It was built in 2001, manufactured home.